# Too many files open

Tags: python-imaging-library, pytorch

```
import PIL as Image
Image.fromarray(cv2.imread(link, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
```

I'm currently trying to complete a project but I'm constantly getting too many files open error on my linux GPU server which crashes the server.

I'm loading 3 images for CNN classification using the code as shown above. Anyone facing the same problem have a solution to this?

Thank you.

Comment: You should add more information. What is the size of your dataset? Batch size? The relevant error message should also be posted. You should also polish your writing to make it clear. See also [how to ask good question](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)

Answer (score 5):

Try switching to the file strategy system by adding this to your script

```
import torch.multiprocessing
torch.multiprocessing.set_sharing_strategy('file_system')
```

Comment: Hi Silas, the administrator of the server has already increased the maximum file limit but it seems it might be some problem with how my image is loaded using the pytorch dataloader. I'm trying to see if anyone is facing the same problem as me.

Comment: the default file_descriptor share strategy uses file descriptors as shared memory handles, and this will hit the limit when there are too many batches at DataLoader and this case it's the images you're using

Comment: https://pytorch.org/docs/master/multiprocessing.html?highlight=sharing%20strategy#sharing-strategies